# How to perform a conditional count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need some help with a very specific question (so i think) and I hope it's solvable.

I have a table which look like this:

| cdts | vehicle | device |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20211101 | car1 | deviceX |
| 20211101 | car1 | deviceY |
| 20211101 | car1 | deviceZ |
| 20211101 | car2 | deviceX |
| 20211101 | car2 | deviceY |
| 20211101 | car3 | deviceX |
| 20211101 | car3 | deviceY |
| 20211102 | car1 | deviceX |
| 20211102 | car1 | deviceY |
| 20211102 | car2 | deviceZ |
| 20211102 | car2 | deviceX |
| 20211102 | car2 | deviceY |
| 20211102 | car3 | deviceX |
| 20211102 | car3 | deviceY |

I need to get a list how often a car had 2 devices or 3 devices, so it should look like this:

| vehicle | 2 Devices | 3 Devices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car1 | 1 | 1 |
| car2 | 1 | 1 |
| car3 | 2 | 0 |

I don't really know how to get this right. Do I need subqueries, can I do a count() with a where clause?

Comment: You first need to tag which backend you are using (postgreSQL, SQL Server, ...?). Oh T_SQL sorry, so I assume it is SQL server, right?

Comment: @CetinBasoz Given the mention of TSQL, I have assumed SQL Server, though it could also be Sybase.

Comment: Can a car have quantity 2 (or more) of a particular device? How would that affect your counts, i.,e. are you interested in _distinct_ devices?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think I already added it.

Comment: Can you also please explain the logic of counting here.

Comment: What if there is a day with more than 3 devices? Does a 3 device day also count as  2 device day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select vehicle 
     , sum(case when devicecount = 2 then 1 else 0 end) [2Devices]
     , sum(case when devicecount = 3 then 1 else 0 end) [3Devices]
from ( 
    select vehicle, count(device) devicecount
    from table
    group by vehicle,cdts
) t group by vehicle
```

Comment: I don't think this matches the result he wanted but probably OP made typo on the result he wrote.

Comment: See this fiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/926f2/4 Seems like there should also be a way to do this via a windowing function.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes fiddle demo too shows that it doesn't match the result OP wanted (I don't know how OP could deduct result though, likely typo).

Comment: Thank you , this worked perfect for me .

Comment: @Likemike90, so your result you wanted was wrong :) Please mark this as answer then.

Comment: I fixed the sample data. It was clearly a typo.

Comment: But now I have found out that apparently the devices can change in one day. That means a vehicle with 2 devices becomes a vehicle with 3 devices. Is there a solution here that when the number of devices changes, only the higher number counts? In November I have 20 entries on some vehicles even though it only has 15 days.